# What is the difference between Drivers and Container Runtimes in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I was reading about the Minikube installation process and the names Drivers and Containers Runtimes got me confused.

**Drivers**

When I don't choose a driver Minikube will use the Docker driver by default, thus using a Docker daemon inside Minikube itself. When I choose none it'll use the host's Docker daemon. Others can be chosen like podman, KVM, etc.

**Container Runtimes**

When it comes to the Container Runtime I can choose, again, Docker or others like Containerd.

**My Inquire**

What I couldn't find is a more detailed explanation around the differences between Drivers and Container Runtimes. Actually I know that the Runtimes exist to run container in Pods, but what about Drivers? Does the Container Runtime runs on top of the Driver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Drivers**

- Where do you want to run Kubernetes on top of?

  - VMs? -> Hyperkit, VirtualBox, Parallels, VMWare, etc
  - Containers? -> Docker (Ironically, this runs on VM if you are on a Mac or Windows, but not on Linux), Podman, etc.

**Container Runtimes**

- When your cluster gets created how would you like it to be configured? Using what runtime or shim to instantiate its containers (and Pods)?

  - [Containerd](https://containerd.io/) -> It's a shim that understands [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/12/container-runtime-interface-cri-in-kubernetes/) from the kubelet and runs containers with an executable like [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) (the actual runtime, that uses things like [cgcreate](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cgcreate) and [nsenter](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nsenter.1.html))
  - [CRI-O](https://cri-o.io/) -> It's another shim that understands [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/12/container-runtime-interface-cri-in-kubernetes/) from the kubelet and just like Containerd runs containers with an executable like runc
  - Docker -> The kubelet directly talks to the Docker daemon using the [dockershim](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/kubelet/dockershim) that talks to Containerd, that instantiates your containers (I know it's complicated, historical reasons...)

✌️

Comment: So if I use the Docker Runtime, in the end, it'll be used just as a bridge to another runtime?

Comment: Yes, that will basically use Docker -> containerd -> runc

Comment: If one wanted to run nvidia-docker in the "outer privileged container", which option needs to be expanded to allow that?  See the partial answer here: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/10229#issuecomment-765890153